# How to set a value to LiveData.setValue() when loading data is not successful?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components

Let's say I have a User view model to load the user's data. I would use Retrofit2 to load the users data. A simple example would be like this:

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    userMutableLiveData.setValue(response.body());
                } else {
                    //since response.body() is null, how to set a suitable value to userMutableLiveData.setValue()
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
                //since there was a networking failure, how to set a suitable value to userMutableLiveData.setValue()
            }
        });
```

Now my question is when retrofit returns response code is not successful or a networking failure occur how do I set a suitable value **so that I can give the user a good feedback of what happened**.

Comment: Use a separate SingleLiveData

Comment: I never read about SingleLiveData. Would you please attach a link on SingleLiveData.

Comment: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/6419d4c523b67d020120fc400ed5a7372e5615f2/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/SingleLiveEvent.java